# Regarding decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

When i am writing 11.00 it is displaying 11.00.00 otherwise its working fine on rest

```
if(pos == -1)
{
    document.getElementById("printCheckAmount").textContent = "$" + checkObj.checkAmount + ".00";
}
else
{
    var integer = enterCheckAmount.substring(0,pos);
    var decimals = enterCheckAmount.substring(pos+1);
    while(decimals.length<2) decimals=decimals+'0';
    enterCheckAmount = integer + '.' + decimals;
    document.getElementById("printCheckAmount").textContent = "$" + checkObj.checkAmount;
}
```

Comment: add the full code

Comment: check this out: `"$" + checkObj.checkAmount.toFixed(2)`, replaces your whole code.

Comment: its giving an error checkObj.checkAmount.toFixed(2) is not a function

Comment: `toFixed` is a method of `Number`. Check the type of your variable `checkObj.checkAmount` like this: `typeof(checkObj.checkAmount)`. If it returns `"string"` then you have an explanation for the error.

Comment: when i am writing console.log(checkObj.checkAmount) its giving 11.00 which i have entered but when the check is printed its giving 11.00.00

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you have instructed the computer to do. You concatenate a string `"$"` with `11.00` (which can be string or number) and get the string `"$11.00"` and then you concatenate the string `".00"`. This gives `"$11.00.00"`. JavaScript does a type coercion when doing operations on different variable types. "string" + "number" will return a string (Example: `console.log("2" + 2);` will return `22`). You have to refactor your code completely. Using `parseInt` you'll get 11 out of both `11.00` and `"11.00"`. With `.fixedTo(2)` you'll get 2 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: If you adapt the line from @Thomas like this: `"$" + parseFloat(checkObj.checkAmount).toFixed(2)` it should work and replace your whole code. Please read my answer with the explanations. You should understand what is done and how it is done, not just copy-paste the code.

Comment: Thanks @cezar for making me understand the things

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have a variable type for decimal numbers. It has only Number. If you want to display an integer as a decimal number with two zeros after the decimal point you can use the method `toFixed`.

Here is an example:

```
var myNumber = 11;
var myDecimalNumber = myNumber.toFixed(2);
console.log(myDecimalNumber) // will output 11.00
```

Thus there is no need to concatenate strings and add ".00" manually to your number.

Beyond this you can use the methods `parseInt` and `parseFloat`. Let's say you have a variable of type string with the value "11 pieces". You can get the integer with this line of code:

```
var myString = "11 pieces";
var myInteger = parseInt(myString, 10);
console.log(myInteger); // will output 11
```

If you have something similar like this, you are better off with this methods instead of cuting substrings.

I wish you a lot of success in refactoring your code and a warm welcome to the StackOverflow community.